# Script to download file without clicking a button

Tags: python, download, package, mget

The website [Download the GLEIF Golden Copy and Delta Files](https://www.gleif.org/en/lei-data/gleif-golden-copy/download-the-golden-copy#).

has buttons that download data that I want to retrieve automatically with a python script.  Usually when I want to download a file, I use `mget` or similar, but that will not work here (at least I don't think it will).

For some reason I cannot fathom, the producers of the data seem to want to force one to manually download the files.  I really need to automate this to reduce the number of steps for my users (and frankly for me), since there are a great many files in addition to these and I want to automate as many as possible (all of them).

So my question is this - is there some kind of python package for doing this sort of thing?  If not a python package, is there perhaps some other tool that is useful for it?  I have to believe this is a common annoyance.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: This is off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape the URLs then download them with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: I've never used BS like this. I'll give it a try.